# Writing a quadratic form associated with a symmetric matrix as a sum of squares with minors as coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

The following code is an attempt to write a quadratic form associated with a symmetric matrix as a sum of squares:

```
n= 3
symMat = Table[If[i >= j, Subscript[m, j, i], Subscript[m, i, j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
symMatt = 1/Subscript[m, 1, 1] symMat 
cdsymMatt = CholeskyDecomposition[symMatt] //. Conjugate[x_] -> x
xx = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}];
pol = Subscript[m, 1, 1] (xx. Transpose[cdsymMatt]).(cdsymMatt. xx)
```

Now I would like to rewrite `pol` as

$
\qquad pm_1 y_1^2 + \frac{pm_2}{pm_1} y_2^2 + \frac{pm_3}{pm_2} y_3^2
$

where the $pm_i$ are the unevaluated principal minors of `symMat` --- I use here the $y_i$ shortcuts to avoid writing the terms which are in the squares. Of course this should be extended to $n > 3$. I know how to do it step-by-step -- but I wonder if someone has an idea how to make it in a proper way?

---

The final desired form is similar to the following:

[image]

This is taken from Simon and Blume, *Mathematics for Economists* (1994), p. 386; the textbook hints at the derivation of this formula by "completing the square twice".

Comment: I can't follow your question. You seem to imply that all entries in your matrix are real, since you simplify away the conjugates. If so, then `Expand@ Simplify[pol, Element[_, Reals]]` returns [this rather simple result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vdYEV.png). Can you show explicitly how you would like that transformed?

Comment: MarcoB if I only know how to insert an image in a comment I would give your the formula of Simon and Blume p 386 but if you want you can look at it here http://www.repetitfind.ru/Literature/subjects/Blume-Mathematics-for-Economists.pdf

Comment: MarcoB I have understood you point. The problem is to write the quadratic form as the sum of squares ---  no terms as $x_1 x_2$. In such a way you can detect in reading the parameters if it is definite positive, negative or neither he one or the other.

Comment: Cyrille, I've included the result I think you refer to in your question. Please check that it is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I want hopping for n > 3